# all android devices on my LAN can ONLY connect to the gateway

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, networking, wi-fi, 3.1-honeycomb

I have a phone running 2.3 and a tablet running 3.1 on the wireles network along with a bunch of computers. I have a bit of a networking mistery.

Here are the facts:

- all the devices can get the the internet.
- the non-android devices can all connect to each other.
- the android devices can connect to only the gateway not to anything else
- none of the other device can ping the android devices.
- the tablet can connect to local computers on my work's LAN.

on the phone I see only a route to the local netowrk and a default gateway

```
ip address:
... many rmnet addresses ...
eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdic pfifo_fast static UP plen 1000
inet/ether 64:a7:69:70:76:7b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.11.4/24 brd 192.168.11.255 scope global eth0
inet <link local ip6>
```

on the tablet:

```
# ip r
192.168.11.1 dev wlan0  scope link
192.168.11.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.11.6  metric 306
default via 192.168.11.1 dev wlan0
default via 192.168.11.1 dev wlan0  metric 306
#
#
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN
    link/ether 42:cf:a5:fd:26:81 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 1e:2e:a2:c3:16:7e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: sit0: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
5: ip6tnl0: <NOARP> mtu 1460 qdisc noop state DOWN
    link/tunnel6 :: brd ::
6: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:6d:04:39:26:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.11.6/24 brd 192.168.11.255 scope global wlan0
    inet6 fe80::f66d:4ff:fe39:2621/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

also on the tablet i see that the problem is arp requests failing:

```
# ping 192.168.11.100
PING 192.168.11.100 (192.168.11.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.11.3 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.11.3 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.11.3 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.11.100 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4005ms, pipe 3
# ip neighbor show
192.168.11.100 dev wlan0  FAILED
192.168.11.1 dev wlan0 lladdr 00:16:01:a1:a4:18 STALE
#
```

Comment: should i move this to server fault?  it's android specific, but also about networking?

Comment: Sounds to me like something to do with Android, it's probably OK to stay here.  I just checked and I can't ping my Android phone on my wireless network ... interesting.  Considering I can remote desktop from the phone into my laptop.

Comment: Any chance you have MAC address filtering or something else in place that would be blocking your devices from the rest of your network?

Comment: checked the router config and confirmed that the mac filtering is off, as well as "privacy separation"

Answer (score 1):

broke out the packet sniffer and determined that broadcast arp request from android devices where being dropped in the access point.

turned out to be a bug with my Buffalo 300n wireless access point. 
cheep new AP and problem gone... apparently some APs just don't talk to Android?

solved by using the principal of "replace the cheapest things first"